# Mysql add column from another table (no reference id)

Tags: php, mysql, database, xsd

Table **small** contains
`column A varchar(10)
 column B varchar(20)`

Table **skeleton** contains
`column A varchar(10)
 column B varchar(20)
 column C varchar(30)
 column D varchar(40)`

I want to add **column C varchar(30)** from table **skeleton** to **small** table.

Please note **skeleton** contains no data and two table doesn't have any common key to join.

@Ultimater thanks.. but that will not solve the issue.. Actually I don't know which column will be needed to add, it will be based on source data.... **small** table is actually a dynamic table which will grow in times.... skeleton table is like a schema table to get exact column name and type from it. Hope you understand....

@update my data feed for **small table** will be an XML file I do have XSD file also... so if anybody could give any XSD reader library for PHP other than [xsdreader](https://github.com/goetas/xsd-reader) - (which I tried without much success) then it will equally solve my problem... Hope You Understand.

Comment: So which value from the small table should be added to which value from the skeleton? is there any sort of relation between the two tables?

Comment: there is no relation.... i just want to create a column with exact type of skeleton column... small table will have data but skeleton will always be empty.

Comment: in my opinion, if you are trying to add to small table dynamically, maybe you can use @Ultimater's code whenever you need to add a new column.

Comment: I'm not sure... if i follow you.... My data source will be an xml data feed.... it will be read by a php script (scheduler). and fed it to mysql (small table)... A new column may need to be added in small table but it will depend on the xml feed.... i'll get the column name from xml but i need the exact type, length etc... of that column from skeleton table....

Comment: If you are suggesting something like `show fields from skeleton where Field='Column C' `and build a query in PHP.. I would prefer mysql way of doing as like `create table as .....`.... is it possible?

Comment: i see. it is beyond my knowledge area already. i don't know if it is possible im sorry

Comment: @BourneShady Please don't be sorry boss.... i came here because i want to learn something new... also give something new if possible...I appreciate your help.... I've updated my question looking for an alternate possible solution... maybe you can help me on that...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, all you're trying to do is add another column to an already existing table. This is quite simple with phpMyAdmin for example. In your case all you'd need is:

```
ALTER TABLE  `small` ADD `C` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL
```